# setting up a cronjob to execute an api callback URL

Tags: php, api, cpanel

please can anyone give me a clue on how to Set up a cronjob to execute my API callback URL once every 15 mins, since my control panel does not have that ability, please i need specifications with examples because am still at the armature level, example: i want to setup a cronjop to execute this API call back url http://shop.site.com/modules/cashenvoy/validation.php every 15 mins and my control panel dn't have the option for direct cronjob setting, please how do i go about to setup a cronjob to execute this URL, thanks ur suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: -1 cause you could google this within a second. Edit: http://www.google.de/#q=cronjob+every+15+minutes

Comment: google knows it, and there is even youtube clip http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7rnPUjDJW0

Comment: Could you make an example of your API callback URL ?

Answer (score 0):

```
*/15 * * * *       root    /usr/bin/wget -O - http://localhost/your/callback.html >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This is for /etc/crontab - if you want to put this into a per-user crontab (with crontab -e), just omit the "root".

**Please also note that running such a thing as root is a bad idea - you should probably replace "root" with an unprivileged username such as "nobody"**

Answer (score 0):

Many web hosting sites have their own control panel where you can set up and edit cronjobs. For example, in cPanel, there is option for this. Please have a look there first.

If control panel does not have that ability, maybe you could try this command:

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /path/to/command
```

[Source](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/run-cron-command-every-15-minutes/)